# Postgresql - Split a string by hyphen and group by the second part of the string

Tags: postgresql

I have the data stored in the below format :

```
   resource_name      |    readiops   | writeiops  
     90832-00:29:3E        3.21           4.00
     90833-00:30:3E        2.12           3.45
     90834-00:31:3E        2.33           2.78
     90832-00:29:3E        4.21           6.00
```

I want to be able to do a split on **resource_name** column by "-" and group it by the second part of the split so that the above data looks like below :

```
      array_serial         |      ldev        |  readiops    |   writeiops  
       90832                    00:29:3E         3.21,4.21        4.00,6.00
       90833                    00:30:3E         2.12             3.45 
       90834                    00:31:3E         2.33             2.78
```

The resource_name is split into array_serial & ldev .

i have tried using the below query just to get an error .

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(resource_name, 0, STRPOS(resource_name, ':')) AS array_serial,
    SUBSTRING(resource_name,1, STRPOS(resource_name, ':')) AS ldev 
FROM table 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(resource_name, 0, STRPOS(resource_name, ':'))
```

I am new to postgres . So kindly help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
with my_table(resource_name, readiops, writeiops) as (
values
('90832-00:29:3E', 3.21, 4.00),
('90833-00:30:3E', 2.12, 3.45),
('90834-00:31:3E', 2.33, 2.78),
('90832-00:29:3E', 4.21, 6.00)
)

select 
    split_part(resource_name::text, '-', 1) as array_serial,
    split_part(resource_name::text, '-', 2) as ldev,
    string_agg(readiops::text, ',') as readiops,
    string_agg(writeiops::text, ',') as writeiops
from my_table
group by 1, 2;

 array_serial |   ldev   | readiops  | writeiops 
--------------+----------+-----------+-----------
 90832        | 00:29:3E | 3.21,4.21 | 4.00,6.00
 90833        | 00:30:3E | 2.12      | 3.45
 90834        | 00:31:3E | 2.33      | 2.78
(3 rows)
```

Comment: magic . Any reason why the query is taking like 60-70 seconds to execute in a table with 50,000 records ?

Comment: I really don't know. I've tested this on a table with 50000 random rows and got times < 1s. Note however that the query returns several thousand rows, so this may be a time of transmission. Try it e.g. with limit 100.

Comment: it should run faster than that, tested with a 500k records, this query executes in around 2600 ms on a modest server. what version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: My postgres version is 9.3.14 .maybe cuz my db connection is remote and i am using a tool db visualizer to execute queries ? Even if i limit it to 50 or 100 the execution time exceeds 50 seconds . Strange

Comment: @user1411837 - of course, on remote server the transmission time of a large resultset may be many times greater than the execution time. Try limit the results and use simple terminal psql.